# What is the Evangelion reference Araragi was talking about?

Tags: monogatari-series, neon-genesis-evangelion

At the beginning of *Nisemonogatari* before the opening, [we see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbR-L4rf7_Q) Araragi chained and handcuffed in the cram school with Senjōgahara being the perpetrator. At one point, Araragi said that he would be enjoying the moment more if it wasn't for the Evangelion reference.

What is the reference he was talking about? I didn't see anything which hinted at an Evangelion reference.

Comment: Might the EVA tag be useful here? I'm not really sure though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding onto the other answer, the exact thing that gets interpreted as an EVA reference is Senjougahara's line:

> You won't die. [*Short break.*] You won't die. Because I'll protect you.

It is clear that this is probably the content of the "reference", as Araragi makes the comment about wanting "no unnecessary Evangelion references" right after this line.

This is nearly identical to a line between Shinji and Rei in episode 6 of the EVA anime, as [mivilar](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/34/mivilar) has pointed out. In that episode, there is an Angel attacking NERV, which has so far repelled the attacks against it. The solution is to use a very high-power rifle against the Angel from a distance, with Rei acting as a back-up or shield for Shinji.

Prior to the start of the mission, Shinji is worried, and asks Rei if she is scared. In response, she tells him that he shouldn't be scared, that "you won't die; I'll protect you." (The exact wording probably depends on the subtitle set.)

---

**Aside:** Naturally, this suggests that the EVA line is rather notable (something which did not occur to me when I first watched EVA). I would suspect that it has become so partly because of the pacing of the specific scene. Perhaps it's also easier to catch the mirroring of words in Japanese, as this is not a line with very idiosyncratic vocabulary. (Compare to Senjougahara's reference to *Fullmetal Alchemist* in *Bakemonogatari*, where the exact ordering or wording of "X kilos of A, Y grams of B, . . ." doesn't matter too much in terms of the ability of a watcher to catch the reference.)

Comment: That this reference is so hard to catch is probably the reason why Koyomi specifically calls it out as an Eva reference. No one ever does the same with Hitagi's FMA reference, though Tsubasa notices in the novel of Tsubasa Tiger that Hitagi's school notes are mostly just drawings of FMA characters.

Comment: Rei's _watashi ga mamoru mono_ "Because I'll protect you" is easily one of the most famous lines in NGE, and I think Japanese viewers would have easily caught it even if Koyomi hadn't pointed it out (though not as easily as the earlier FMA reference, granted). It's been almost a decade since I watched NGE, and I still have a clear memory of Rei saying that; heck if I know why. It probably doesn't come across that way to the English-speaking viewer, since "Because I'll protect you" is a pretty mundane sentence, all things considered (plus differences in translation, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

This is referencing the conversation between Shinji and Rei in episode 6 while preparing to engage Ramiel. At least that's the best I could think of and evageeks [agrees](http://wiki.evageeks.org/Tributes_to_Neon_Genesis_Evangelion_in_other_Anime_and_Manga#Nisemonogatari_.28.E5.81.BD.E7.89.A9.E8.AA.9E.29).

Click the image below, for the full sequence.

[image: Rei's "I'll protect you in episode 6"]

Comment: At least for me, the YouTube link doesn't work -- the account has been removed for copyright infringement, apparently.

Comment: @Maroon Indeed, thanks. I just took the first one I found. I now added the images instead.

Comment: Here is the referenced scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksLAFbTskO0 > あなたは死なないわ、私が守るもの
>
> You won't die. Because I'll protect you.